# Бесконечная загрузка страницы

Tags: javascript, html, загрузка, dle

Подгружаю html с помощью js так:

```
var cat='{category}';
if((cat!='1')||(cat!='2')||(cat!='3')||(cat!='4')){
document.getElementById('video').innerHTML = '<video controls width="300"  src="URL"></video>'; 
document.getElementById('teggi').innerHTML = '';
}

if((cat=='1')||(cat=='2')||(cat=='3')||(cat=='4')){
  document.getElementById('video').innerHTML = '<iframe src="URL1" style="border:0;width:100%;height:500px;"scrolling="no"></iframe>';  
document.getElementById('nevsunichtoz').innerHTML = '';
}
```

При открытии страницы на которой расположен этот код идет бесконечная загрузка, хотя html вставляется куда нужно и, с виду, страница полностью загрузилась.Если убрать этот код:

```
document.getElementById('video').innerHTML = '<iframe src="URL1" style="border:0;width:100%;height:500px;"scrolling="no"></iframe>';
```

то все нормально работает.

С чем это может быть связано? Как исправить?

Comment: Весь код страницы.. или хотя бы js добавь

Comment: @СергейПетрашко Добавил.

Comment: а что с cat?  if так не пишутся. непонятно что ты хочешь сделать с этими перезаписями. например  если у тебя cat ===2 то у тебя выполнится сначало первое условие так как первая проверка cat!=1 ===true, но потом выполнится и вторая так как сат ===2. и с url  в iframe  непонятно

Comment: @СергейПетрашко Да- это я зевнул. Поместил первые замены в else второй части и заработало нормально. Это изменение содержания в зависимости от категорий- если категории такие то, то одно содержание, если нет, то иное. Выходит оно как то меняло много раз подряд?(В ответ пож.) Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ошибка, приводящая к перезагрузке в некорректном   url  в src. исправь на нужный, и разберись с if.  в первом if  скорее всего нужно не или а и (& вместо  ||)